# How to save a value in table's column based on the value sent in httprequest?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using a spring boot application. From postman I send the JSON

```
{  
   "id":2, 
    "name": "Niki" ,
    "empType":"SENIOR"
}
```

Now if the empType in the request is "SENIOR" then I have to save "C-9" in the employee type column, If it is "JUNIOR" then I should  save "C-10" in the employee type column.Please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two scenarios. By using a custom **JsonDeserializer** class provided by Jackson or utilizing a setter method.

In the first scenario:

1. Create an EmployeeDTO model class with the necessary fields:

```java
    public class EmployeeDTO {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String empType;
    // Getters and setters 
}
```

2. Implement a custom **deserializer** that maps the JSON values to the desired representation:

```java
public class EmployeeTypeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        String empType = jsonParser.getValueAsString();
        if ("SENIOR".equals(empType)) {
            return "C-9";
        } else if ("JUNIOR".equals(empType)) {
            return "C-10";
        }
        return empType;
    }
}
```

3. Annotate the empType property in the EmployeeDTO class with **@JsonDeserialize** to specify the usage of the custom deserializer:

```java
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeeTypeDeserializer.class)
private String empType;
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the desired mapping by using a setter method:

```java
public void setEmpType(String empType) {
    System.out.println("Setter method called");
    if (empType.equals("SENIOR")) {
        this.empType = "C-9";
    } else if (empType.equals("JUNIOR")) {
        this.empType = "C-10";
    } else {
        // Handle the case when empType is not the desired type
        // You can choose to throw an exception or set the empType to null or an empty string
        // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid empType");
        // this.empType = null;
        this.empType = "";
    }
}
```

Depending on your business logic, you can decide how to handle the case when empType does not match the desired types, whether by throwing an exception or setting it to null.

You can even set the empType in the service layer.